# Call a Secured Web Service from SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, webservices, security, ssjs

I have a task to call a secured web service from a SFMC Microsite. I understand this can be achieved by -

1. Importing the Private Certificate on SFMC (Admin -> Data Management -> Key Management), but when I try that the screen blanks out. Not sure if I am doing anything wrong there or is it just a temporary UI issue.
2. Use SSJS Post Method to make the call. How do I pass security details like username/password and that it has to use an imported certificate to make the call.

Adding information - We are trying to call a secure external web service. We have been provided a certificate and a keystore to call the web service. I am trying to figure out where can we store the certificate on SFMC and how do we pass on the security details in SOAP Header while making the call via SSJS.

Thanks.

Comment: Please update your question with details about the _secured web service_ you mentioned.  What is required to connect?

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario doesn't sound like a use-case for SFMC's [Key Management](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/encryption_key_management/), which is primarily for encrypting data, FTP access with a key or single sign-on for your for your accessing your SFMC account.